# Determine what is the angle of an complex number without imaginary value

Tags: complex-numbers, angle

Okay, so this is bugging me now.

I know this:

while tg angle = Y / X

for y > 0, angle is an element of < 0, PI >

for y < 0, angle is an element of < PI, 2PI >

for y = 0, angle is 0 or PI or 2PI.

Okay, but how to determine what out of those 3 values angle actually is ?

So far this is what I know:

If X is negative, angle should be PI, and if X is positive, angle should be either 0 or 2PI... And thats bugging me now, how do I know if its 2PI or 0 ?

EDIT:

I am asking this because if I assume that angle is 0, while calculating root of complex number I would use:

r * cis ((0 + 2*k*PI) / n)

and if I assume that angle is 2PI, it would be

r * cis ((2PI + 2*k*PI) / n)

What should I assume my angle is when y = 0 and x > 0 ?:/

Comment: This question already has a downvote and it's likely to get more. Here are some suggestions for how you can improve the question and maybe get some useful answers. 1.It's not clear what you're asking. 2.Your title doesn't seem to match the content of the question. 3.You neglected to use MathJax which really bothers people here.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace k in the second expression by k-1, you will get the first expression for r*cis.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that.. I am talking about assuming wheather my angle should be 0 or 2PI (if y = 0, x > 0)and WHY, not if k = 0 or 1 or 2 or 10....

Answer (score 0):

The choice of which among the numbers $\phi + 2k\pi$ should be "the" angle is a matter of convention only. Whichever value of $k$ you choose you will always get the same complex number from $r\text{ cis} (\phi  $).

For complex numbers off the positive real axis the convention is (as you know) to use an angle strictly between $0$ and $2\pi$. For numbers on the axis the usual convention is that the angle is $0$.

To summarize: it's just a convention and you can stop letting it bug you.

Comment: Okay I'll use 0 then

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking if the solution to $z^4=1$ should be $z=1$ from $k=0$ or $z=i$ from $k=2.$ But there are also $z=-1$ and $z=-i$ from $k=4$ and $k=6.$ Actually, $z=-i$ results from $(6+8j)\pi.$ One might consider $i$ the "nicest" solution. In general, the solution coming from $2\pi$ is sometimes **informally** referred to as the [principal primitive root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalRootofUnity.html).

If you wanted to look at complex numbers with $x\gt 0$ it would be most convenient to use angles between $-\frac{\pi}2$ and  $\frac{\pi}2$ as , for example, with $\arctan.$

Sometimes it is convenient to make a certain choice but the others are equally valid.

By the way, at $(0,0)$ the angle is totally undetermined, but not undefined. Any choice at all is valid, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: As a reference: `Math.Atan2(0,0)` in .NET produces `0`.

Comment: I don't know .NET but, yes $\arctan(x)$ is the unique angle $\theta$ with $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$ and $\tan(\theta)=x$, The solutions to $tan(\theta)=x$ are $\theta=\alpha+k\pi$ where $\alpha$ is any particular solution. Nicest is to use $\theta=\arctan(x)+k\pi.$